# extend existing event in custom control ui5

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I'd like to extend (not override) the existing UI5 event of MultiComboBox component.

I found that https://github.com/SAP/openui5/blob/master/src/sap.m/src/sap/m/MultiComboBox.js

has MultiComboBox.prototype._handleSelectionLiveChange, how do I actually extend it in my own custom control?

Here is what I've done:

```
sap.ui.define([
  'sap/m/MultiComboBox',
  'sap/m/HBox'
  ], function (MultiComboBox, HBox) {
  return MultiComboBox.extend('TokenizedMultiComboBox', {
    metadata: {
      aggregations: {
        _hbox: { type: 'sap.m.HBox', multiple: false }
      }
    },

    init: function () {
      MultiComboBox.prototype.init.apply(this, arguments);
      this.setAggregation('_hbox', new HBox({
        items: []
      }));
    },

    onAfterRendering: function() {
      const hbox = this.getAggregation('_hbox');
    },

    _handleSelectionLiveChange: function() {
      // should my code go here or?
    },

    renderer: function (rm, oControl) {
      sap.m.MultiComboBoxRenderer.render(rm, oControl);
      rm.write('<div');
      rm.writeControlData(oControl);
      rm.write('>');
      rm.write('<div>');
      rm.renderControl(oControl.getAggregation('_hbox'));
      rm.write('</div>');
      rm.write('</div>');
    },
  })
})
```

Comment: this function name has a leading underscore which mean that this function is private. Hence it is not a good idea to extend it. maybe you can state what are your requirements and we can help you out. thanks

Comment: thanks for the answer, my requirement is to getItems from the `MultiComboBox` with their key/value pairs and pass them into the `hBox` once there's a selection in MultiComboBox occured.

Comment: actually from this example https://jsbin.com/puyetaq/ it's more or less done, but in my case I am extending the existing control

Comment: the way that you have the renderer in the code is incorrect. For this reason, I do not recommend that you extend control; and to create composite control

Comment: I have to define a lot of parameters from view xml in my MultiCombobox like `selectionChange`, `selectionFinish` , `palceholder` , `items`, would that be possible with the composite control?

Comment: not the way how you think it should be implemented. maybe it requires a bit of creativity and thinking. We can create more complex controls in the past and we never have issues.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214601/discussion-between-ren-and-d-seah).